# Rails Route only with numeric param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, routes

i have in my application a custom route, that need to match everytime the param is a number or an list of numbers splited by `|`

this is my code:

```
get '/lists' => 'cidades#list'
get '/list(/:id)' => 'cidades#list', :constraints => { :id => /[0-9|]+/ }
get '/list(/:name)' => 'cidades#list'
```

what i hope to accomplish is something like this:

```
/lists => cidades#list

/list/1 => cidades#list & param[:id] = "1"
/list/1|2|3|4 => cidades#list & param[:id] = "1|2|3|4"

/list/1a => cidades#list & param[:name] = "1a"
```

if i use this regexp: `/[0-9|]+/` i get `1a` to be valid, but i don't want this. I find this regexp: `/\A[0-9|]+\Z/` but this gives me this error:

```
ArgumentError (Regexp anchor characters are not allowed in routing requirements: /\A[0-9|]+\Z/):
```

how can i create a constraint that will only match a numeric string? ( a string with only numbers )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default rails anchors the routing regular expressions so there is no need for the `\A` and `\Z`.  I think you're looking for something that follows this pattern:

```
:constraints => { :id => /[0-9]+(\%7C[0-9]+)*/ }
```

This will force the route to have at least one integer (0-9).  Optionally, the route can be followed by a | character (which is converted to `%7C` by the browser).  The | character is then followed by an additional integer (0-9).  Putting this patter in its own group prevents having any lingering | after the integer ids.

Comment: i don't want "at least one integer" i want only numbers on my param. like: "123" this should be accepted, "123a" this shouldn't be accepted , if possible i want to split this string with "|" or ",". so basically, this is valid: "123", "1", "123,123,123,123", "123|123|123" and this is not valid: "12a", "a123", "1s1", and so on

Comment: I updated the regular expression to accommodate any amount of integers but not characters.  If you want to change the separator from a | character, you can change "\%7C" to the character of your choice.  Here's a list of what the special characters will be converted to by the browser: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Answer (score 0):

You have to use something else than the spesial character | it's not allowed in urls.

I am not really sure what you are trying to do here. But, you could pass the :id's as an array of ids.

ids = [1,2,3,4]